# Stack multiple columns on top of eachother on Google Sheet?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am using Google SpreadSheet, and I'm trying to import data from different sources together using a combination of query, importrange and curly brackets:

```
={Query(Importrange(SheetA),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null");
Query(Importrange(SheetB),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null")}
```

However, the resulting formula only returns SheetA data.

Since I only need 4 particular columns from SheetA and SheetB, I'd want the columns from both sheets to stack on top of each other like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data SheetA | Data SheetA | Data SheetA | Data SheetA |
| Data SheetB | Data SheetB | Data SheetB | Data SheetB |

I tried running each *=query(importrange)* individually and combining them afterward using {A:D;E:H} but it gives ***Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows*** error.

I tried looking for other similar threads but they were mostly about stacking different columns into one singular column. Can you help me with my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to run every importrange separately as standalone formula to connect your sheets by allowing access

when done, only then, you can run this array:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url_or_id", "SheetA!A:D"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("url_or_id", "SheetB!A:D")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

Comment: this works wonderfully, after giving each individual sources importrange approvals. Thank you sm!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was due to the infinite blank rows when trying to combine 2 infinite ranges A:D and E:H,

By enclosing them with a query, remove null value condition, my formula works fine now:

```
=query({A:D;E:H},"Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Nevertheless, are there any ways to stack those 4 columns using the original singular formula using query, importrange and curly brackets?

```
={Query(Importrange(SheetA),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null");
Query(Importrange(SheetB),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null")}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have 2 source files (Source1, Source2), and you want to use stack the data using IMPORTRANGE into another file (Combined)

There are 2 parts to this solution, and you can do Part 1 and Part 2 in any order.

#### Part 1

Give approvals to each of the imported ranges.

On a temporary sheet (that can be removed later) in the Combined file.

Use a standard IMPORTRANGE formula like this for Source1 (example, where you must replace "Source1_ID" with the ID of your Source1 file):

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/Source1_ID", "Sheet1!A2:D")
```

After you have given approval, delete the formula from the cell, and do it again for Source2 (example, where you must replace "Source2_ID" with the ID of your Source2 file)

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/Source2_ID", "Sheet1!A2:D")
```

#### Part 2

In the Combined file, go to the sheet where you want the combined data, and enter in the complete QUERY formula (example, where you must replace "Source1_ID" and "Source2_ID" with the ID's of both of your source files)

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/Source1_ID", "Sheet1!A2:D"); IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/Source2_ID", "Sheet1!A2:D")}, "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 Where Col1 Is Not Null")
```

Answer (score 0):

So we have 3 things to do:

- Transpose so the columns are below the other.
- Flatten so that it is ordered as necessary.
- Filter to remove extra blank columns we selected.

This will work wonders considering the columns are different lengths and are already next to each other as in a table.

If columns are at multiple places use `{A:A;D:D}` to select columns and remove flatten and transpose.

```
=filter(flatten(transpose(A1:D10)), len(flatten(transpose(A1:D10))))
```